Oneplus 12 Bluetooth BLE bug
My new OnePlus 12 (Android 14) is losing Bluetooth BLE connection on daily base.
The 'normal' Bluetooth is functioning fine.
When I clear the Bluetooth cache, BLE is functioning again, for a number of hours / day.
Is there anything I can do to extract the cause of the problem. Log files and where to find them?
The more specific the better I can approach OnePlus for a solution.
I tried what was working and what not so I found out it is a BLE bug in OnePlus OxygenOS14 or Android 14.

Unless this is a problem you're experiencing in an app you are developing, this question is better suited for the Android SE site.
